# Docker Container communication between two .Net Core api services

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I am in the process of learning Docker and I have hit a stumbling block.
I have a Microservices project that I want to be be able to run and debug(in Visual Studio) using docker.

My docker-compose-yml is:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  orderapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}orderapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/WebUI/Dockerfile   
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
    depends_on:
      - sqldata
      - rabbitmq

  productapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}productapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ProductAPI/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
    depends_on:
      - sqldata
      - rabbitmq

  sqldata:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    environment:
       - "SA_PASSWORD=Your_password123"
       - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"
    ports:
    -   "5433:1433"
    networks:
      - rmv-network

  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: "rabbitmq"
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    networks:
      - rmv-network

  signalr:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}signalr
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SignalR/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - orderapi
      - productapi


  retailinmotionmvc:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}retailinmotionmvc
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RetailInMotionMVC/Dockerfile
```

And docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  orderapi:
    container_name: orderapi
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - "UseInMemoryDatabase=false"
      - "ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=sqldata;Database=RetailInMotion.OrderDb;User Id=sa;Password=Your_password123"
      - EventBusConnection=${RIM_AZURE_SERVICE_BUS:-rabbitmq}
      - EventBusUserName=${RIM_SERVICE_BUS_USERNAME:-guest}
      - EventBusPassword=${RIM_SERVICE_BUS_PASSWORD:-guest}
    ports:
      -   "5001:80"
      -   "5000:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - rmv-network

  productapi:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - "UseInMemoryDatabase=false"
      - "ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=sqldata;Database=RetailInMotion.ProductDb;User Id=sa;Password=Your_password123"
      - EventBusConnection=${RIM_AZURE_SERVICE_BUS:-rabbitmq}
      - EventBusUserName=${RIM_SERVICE_BUS_USERNAME}
      - EventBusPassword=${RIM_SERVICE_BUS_PASSWORD}
    ports:
       - "80"
       - "7122:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - rmv-network


  signalr:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - EventBusConnection=${RIM_AZURE_SERVICE_BUS:-rabbitmq}
      - EventBusUserName=${RIM_SERVICE_BUS_USERNAME}
      - EventBusPassword=${RIM_SERVICE_BUS_PASSWORD}
      - SignalrHubUrl=http:${ESHOP_EXTERNAL_DNS_NAME_OR_IP}:5202
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "7071:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - rmv-network

  retailinmotionmvc:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "7166:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - rmv-network

networks:
  rmv-network:
    external: true
```

I have an mvc application service that interacts with an api service.

```
async public Task<List<Order>> GetOrders()
    {
        var uri = API.Order.GetOrders(_orderServiceBaseUrl);

        //var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"/api/order");
        var test = _settings.Value.Urls.SignalrHubUrl;

        var responseString = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);

        var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(responseString, new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        });

        return response.items;
    }
```

The following line is what is causing the issue:

> var responseString = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);

The _orderServiceBaseUrl is :

> $"{settings.Value.Urls.Order}/api/order";

And this is retrieved from the appsettings file. Which is set up as follows:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Urls": {
    //"Order": "192.168.8.112:5000",
    //"Order": "https://localhost:5000", This works when running app locally with docker
    //"Order": "https://172.23.0.4:5000", - Docker ip address
    //"Order": "http://host.docker.internal:5001",
    "SignalrHubUrl": "https://localhost:7071"
  }
}
```

As the block of code above shows I have tried a number of different ip address and have had no joy with any of them.

[image]

Would anyone be able to assist me as to what I am doing wrong in my setup and why I cannot get the docker containers to communicate with each other? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to set the URL of you OrderApi like this in the appsettings.json `"Order": "http://orderapi"` ?

Comment: Hi @JonasWeinhardt I tried it there and got the following: `An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SocketException: Connection refused
System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

HttpRequestException: Connection refused (orderapi:5000)
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(string host, int port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` Any ideas why my connection is refused?

Comment: How exactly did you set the URL in the appsettings.json? The exception suggests you added the port 5000 to it?

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt the 5000 port I believe is being taken from the ports section which I have set above in the orderapi service of the docker-compose.override.yml file above. Do you know how I can change this to 443?

Comment: Can you maybe show me your current "Urls" section of the appsettings.json?

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt I have tried the following: `  "Urls": {
    //"Order": "192.168.8.112:5000",
    //"Order": "https://localhost:5000", This works when running app locally with docker
    //"Order": "https://172.23.0.4:5000", - Docker ip address
    //"Order": "http://host.docker.internal:5001",
    //"Order": "http://orderapi:80",
    "SignalrHubUrl": "https://localhost:7071"
  }`

Comment: And when you simply try `"Order": "http://orderapi"` it does not work?

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt `"Order": "http://orderapi"` does not work. For some reason i get the error orderapi:5000 is refused. i am not sure why the 5000 is being added

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt. Your solution worked. Thank you very much for your help. The issue was I had added app.UseHttpsDirection to the start up classes of each of the projects. Do you know if there is a way to enable using https within a docker environment?